# Extending automorphism to inner automorphism?

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

As a prequel to Problem 56 on [this](https://www.math.kent.edu/%7Ewhite/qual/list/group.pdf) problem set

> 56. Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$ and assume $H$ is isomorphic to $K$. Prove that there exists a group $\bar G$ containing $G$ as a subgroup, such that $H$ and $K$ are conjugate in $\bar G$.

I've decided to start with a simplified version:

> Given a group $G$ and $\phi\in\text{Aut}(G)$, find a group $\bar G\geq G$ such that there exists $\psi\in\text{Int}(\bar G)$ such that $\psi|_G=\phi$.

In reality Problem 56 doesn't imply my statement so I'm not even sure if it's true! but if it is then I find it cool.

My attempt goes as follows.

Construct $\bar G=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}Gx^k$ for some external $x$. Define, for all $g\in G$, $$xg=\phi(g)x$$ or equivalently $$x^kg=\phi(g)x^k\quad\forall\,k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

I'd say this operation, together with the standard product from $G$, endows $\bar G$ with a group structure. Moreover for all $g\in G$ we have that
$$^xg=\phi(g)$$
so that $\psi_x|_G=\phi$.

To prove that my operation is well defined is what I'm not so sure of how to do. Is it fine if I take $y\in \bar G$ and argue that it's uniquely expressed as $y=gx^k,g\in G,k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and that my operation in $\bar G$ (which I'll denote $\cdot$) really means
$$(gx^k)\cdot (hx^\ell)=g\phi^k(h)x^{k+\ell}$$
and now prove associativity, existence of neutral, etc?

We've never actually *constructed* a group from another in class. Also, is there a standard way to define $\bar G$, such as
$$\{gx^k:g\in G,k\in \mathbb{Z},xg=\phi(g)x\}$$
or something along those lines?

Comment: This sort of construction is called an HNN extension (after Higman and two Neumanns).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I won't spoil the fun of solving it myself though.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't think so, since according to my rules that form simplifies down to $\phi(g_1)\phi^{-1}(g_2)\phi^2(g_3)x$. Actually since $xG=Gx$, we have that $G\unlhd\bar G$.

Comment: Alternatively one could have $\bar G=G\times\mathbb{Z}$ and define $(g,x)\cdot (h,y)=(g\phi^x(h),x+y)$. Then $G$ is isomorph by some $\psi$ to $G\times \{0\}$ and $\psi\circ\phi\circ\psi^{-1}$ is conjugation by $(1,1)$ restricted to $G\times \{0\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your simplified version properly. Your $\bar{G}$ is just the semidirect product $G \rtimes_\phi \langle x \rangle$, where you can take $x$ to have the same order as $\phi$ (which might be infinite). Yes, this does what you want.

Comment: Exciting stuff, exciting stuff!