# Adding commutation rules to a free group?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I'm interested in knowing how, given a set $S$, one can modify the free group $F(S)$ by adding one or more commutation rules and get a new group. For instance, adding the commutation rule:
$$\forall x,y\in S, xy=yx$$
yields the free abelian group generated by the base $S$. So I'm wondering: does any commutation rule work? For instance, if I say
$$\forall x,y\in S, xy=yx^2$$
or even that, for a fixed $z\in S$,
$$\forall y\in S,y\neq z, zy=y^{-1}z^2$$
the first is only possible in the trivial group ($x=x1=1x^2=x^2$) but the second does seem to make sense, at least at a first glance, Which, in general, of these rules produces a new group as compared to those which induce a contradiction or work only in the trivial group? Is there for example a big family of such rules that will tune the original free group into a different, non trivial one?

[**Note:** I'm not sure what a proper definition of "commutation rule" could be. I just threw some random examples that fit my intuition for such a term.]

In particular, take the following example.

As a continuation of my previous post ([Extending automorphism to inner automorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842958/extending-automorphism-to-inner-automorphism)), I think I've come to a solution to the following problem.

> 56. Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$ and assume $H$ is isomorphic to $K$. Prove that there exists a group $\bar G$ containing $G$ as a subgroup, such that $H$ and $K$ are conjugate in $\bar G$.

(Problem 56 on [this problem set](https://www.math.kent.edu/%7Ewhite/qual/list/group.pdf).)

Let $\phi:H\to K$ be an isomorphism. My idea is to modify the free group in $G\cup\{x\}$, $F(G\cup\{x\})$, by letting all the elements of $G$ multiply themselves as usual and by adding the following commutation property.
$$\forall h\in H,xh=\phi(h)x$$
Call this new group $\bar G$. This way, $G\leq\bar G$ and for all $h\in H$, $^xh=\phi(h)$ and in particular $^xH=K$.

[**Note:** I know I've added another rule (the one about the elements of $G$ multiplying themselves as usual) but that one could radically be seen as a "commutation property": $\forall g,h\in G, gh=g\cdot_Gh$.]

As I'm not sure if this definition is enough by itself, here's a more schematic definition of $\bar G$.
$$\bar G=\{g_1x^{k_1}g_2x^{k_2}\ldots g_nx^{k_n}:g_i\in G,g_{i>1}\notin H,k_i\in\mathbb{Z},k_{i<n}\neq 0\}$$
Two elements are equal if they have the same canonical form, i.e. the same expression as an interleaved product of elements of $G$ and powers of $x$, subject of the same conditions that I included in the previous definition. The product of two elements is carried out by concatenating their canonical forms and then commuting all the $g_i$'s that belong to $H$, possibly cancelling out some powers of $x$ in the process: since there are only finitely many powers of $x$ in their expressions, this process necessarily ends, yielding the canonical form of their product.

- Does my "commutation rule" actually generate a new group here?
- If so, is it a special case or is there a bigger family of "commutation rules" that will produce a group?

Comment: You might be interested in looking up the definition of a *group presentation*. It is exactly what you are describing: adding relations to a free group.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group

Comment: If you adjoin, for example, the relations $x^2=e, y^3=e, xy=yx$ in the free group generated by $x,y$, you get $\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_2$; this is denoted by $$\langle x,y\mid x^2, y^3, xy=yx\rangle.$$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Concerning Problem 56, it has already been pointed out that the construction to do this is known as the HNN extension. Rather than try and re-invent the wheel, you would be better advised to study that in detail, from a suitable textbook.

Comment: I'll definitely look into HNN, when I've solved my rootedmost doubts by myself!

Comment: @Shaun I'm most grateful for your answer and comments and upvoted what I considered meritorious. However since I'm also expecting an answer to whether my construction *is* actually a valid presentation, I'll keep the ✓ for later!

Comment: You're welcome.  Just let $$R=\{\varphi (a,b,c,\dots)(\psi(x,y,z,\dots))^{-1}\mid a,b,c,\dots, x,y,z,\dots\in F\}$$ to get  $$\varphi (a,b,c,\dots)=\psi(x,y,z,\dots)$$ for all elements in the group. Remember: it works for *any subset $R$ of $F$.*

Comment: I have edited my answer, @LucaT.Castrillón

Comment: The presentation  that you propose generated by $G$ and the extra generator $x$ certainly define a group, but you have to prove that $G$ embeds into this group or, equivalently that the relations do not have any unexpected consequences. That is also equivalent to every group element having a unique normal form of the type described in $\bar{G}$. So you could try and define the group by taking the set of normal forms as the group elements, but then you would have to show that multiplication in this group is associative. All I am doing in this comment is to tell you about the HNN.

Comment: There were 3 people working on that... Better have proven beast results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is, in essence, a [group presentation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group). The study of presentations is known as *combinatorial group theory*.

The theory can get technical very quickly, but the idea is that you take a free group $F=\langle X\rangle$ generated by a set $X$ and a set $R$ of elements of $F$ written in terms of $X$, then the group you're after is

$$G\cong F/\langle\langle R\rangle \rangle,$$

where $\langle\langle R\rangle \rangle$ is the normal subgroup of $F$ generated by $R$. If you want $u=v$, then put $r=uv^{-1}\in R$.

The notation is

$$G\cong\langle X\mid R\rangle,$$

with set notation omitted if the context is clear. For example,

$$\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3\cong \langle a,b\mid a^2, b^3, aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle,$$

also written

$$\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3\cong \langle a,b\mid a^2, b^3, ab=ba\rangle.$$

---

*Every group has a presentation; in fact, each group has infinitely many of them!*

---

Just let $$R\supseteq \{\varphi (a,b,c,\dots)(\psi(x,y,z,\dots))^{-1}\mid a,b,c,\dots, x,y,z,\dots\in F\}$$ to get  $$\varphi (a,b,c,\dots)=\psi(x,y,z,\dots)$$ for all elements in the group. Remember: it works for *any subset $R$ of $F$.*

Comment: What's with the downvote?